# Resampling embedded raster images in SVG

Tags: svg, image-manipulation, resampling

I have a batch of SVG files with embedded, high-res PNG images. The PNG files have been resized considerably smaller (via `transform`, `matrix`, etc). What is the best way to [resample](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/331/331327.html#main_Resizing_and_resampling_images) these embedded images *in place*? The goal is to get smaller, faster-loading SVG files.

Just to clarify some terminology (emphasis added):

> **Resampling** changes the total number of pixels in the image...
>
> ...
>
> When you **resize** an image and do not resample it, you change the size of the image without changing the amount of data...

Clearly, I am only resizing the images right now.

I have toyed with trying to automate it using ImageMagick, but keeping the image proportions is not entirely trivial. Is there a simple Inkscape hack? Or something else I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inkscape does in fact have a resample option (it [may](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/379977) be part of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)). These options are available from the `Extensions -> Raster` menu.

To resample items in your image:

1. Embed the images via `Extensions -> Images -> Embed Images...`
2. Select the embedded image(s)
3. Resample via `Extensions -> Raster -> Resample`

[image]

4. Decrease the `Width` and `Height` values to the lowest acceptable values
5. `Apply` and `Close`

This method will work well during the authoring process. I am still working on a way to automate this and will update this post if I find a good method.

Answer (score 2):

If ImageMagick did not work the way you needed, try out GraphicsMagick (homepage [here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org)).  Yes, it is a fork of ImageMagick but I have at one occasion banged my head against ImageMagick because of a feature being incompletely and/or incorrectly implemented, only to find that the same feature worked like a charm (and in a way I found logical and consistent) in GraphicsMagick.

Yes, this in anecdotal evidence in the direction to try out GraphicsMagick, but it is worth a shot I think. (In general, I find ImageMagick to be a solid piece of software.  It is just some cases where GraphicsMagick is more reliable and thus I stick to it.)

Comment: Well, I sure can't argue with your final sentence -- I just installed it and the viewer displayed the SVG when IM's version of it displayed a blank page! Thanks! Unfortunately, it doesn't help the issue of editing the graphics in place.